# instanceof throwing incompatible types

Tags: java, oop, instanceof

I recently came across a strange compilation error for my following code snippet :

```
class A {

}

class B extends A {

}

class Example {

}

class Demo {
    public static void main (String args[]){
        B b = new B();
        if(b instanceof Example) {
              System.out.println("Yes it is");
        }    
    }
}
```

Now I am getting a compilation error on my predicate indicating that `B` and `Example` are incompatible operands. I searched for a while and found that the Eclipse environment shows such an error if the right hand operand is not imported. But in my case all the classes are in the same file. So I am unable to figure out the issue. Is it that `instanceof` only works for the hierarchies and the example I have been trying an invalid one?

Comment: There is no inheritance linkup between B and Example.So that exception.

Comment: @Dev exceptions are thrown in runtime - this isn't an exception, it's a compilation error

Comment: yes it should be compiler error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`b` is defined as B, it can never be `Example` as there is no inheritance relationship between the two. You would rather do:

```
class Demo {
    public static void main (String args[]){
        A a = new B();
        if(a instanceof B) {
          System.out.println("Yes it is");
        }    
    }
}
```

or if you insist on a type which can hold Example it would be:

```
class Demo {
    public static void main (String args[]){
        Object o = new Example();
        if(o instanceof Example) {
          System.out.println("Yes it is");
        }    
    }
}
```

The compilier can and must check, if the type can be the given instance, see [JLS 15.20.2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.20.2)

> If a cast of the RelationalExpression to the ReferenceType would be rejected as a
>   compile-time error, then the instanceof relational expression likewise produces a
>   compile-time error. In such a situation, the result of the instanceof expression
>   could never be true.

Comment: Yes eckes, I know that the above code shall work but is it strictly defined that `instanceof`  must only be used when the participating operands are in the same hierarchies?

Comment: Yes, the compiler can and must statically assert that. I added it to the answer.

Answer (score 2):

There is absolutely no way that the object referenced by `b` can be an instance of `Example`. This is known at compile time.

A reference of type `B` exists in this hierarchy

```
class B extends A {

}
```

while `Example` is in

```
class Example {}
```

There is no way a variable of type `B` can be referencing an object of type `Example`. For example, an instance of type `B` is already, obviously, not a subtype of `Example`. Furthermore, any subtype of `B` would be a subclass of `B`. Since Java doesn't support multiple inheritance, then it could not also be a subtype of `Example`. (The same could not be said if `Example` was an `interface`.)

Comment: That's a great point there Sotirios. When I made Example as an interface it no longer produced an error.

Comment: @Sourabh That's because you can create a subclass of `B` which does implement `Example`. You could then create an instance of that class and assign it to `b`.

Answer (score 1):

The `instanceof` operator is used for runtime type checking. It would make sense, for example, to check if a reference of type `A` actually holds a `B` instance. However, `Example` and `B` are completely disjoint types - a reference to `B` can **never** hold an instance of type `Example`, therefore checking it is pointless, and can be failed at compile time.

Comment: Okay that would be it. I think then that my example was wrong. I never knew that instanceof must only be used when there are two related types and not with disjoint types.

Answer (score 1):

**instanceof** is operator only work of inheritance and implementation . If object you are checking of is not from inheritance hierarchies  then you will get compilation error . Do this below is the code

```
class Demo {
    public static void main (String args[]){
        A obj = new B();
        if(obj instanceof B) {
          System.out.println("Yes it is");
        }    
    }
}
```

Here you cannot check `obj instanceof Example` , its wrong as is not from hierarchies.